# Http 404 error in Hello world Spring MVC Web app fully java configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring Web MVC and I tried to try Hello world app.

I followed an example from "Spring In Action 4th ed" book which only uses java config (without any XML file). I use Tomcat v7.0 server and servlet 3.

The problem is when I try to go to the home page I get Http 404 error.

The used Java classes are :

DispatcherServlet configuration:

```
package config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class FirstWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }
}
```

Spring MVC configuration :

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
        }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Configuration used to get other Beans (doesn't do any thing in the hello world app)

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"lgmi_cr"},excludeFilters={@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)})
public class RootConfig {

}
```

Home page controller

```
package web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";

    }

}
```

A JSP file "home" uneder /WEB-INF/views/

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since it 404 error, my first impression is that it could not find any controller but I don't know why.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you checked your Tomcat log? Maybe your application has not deployed correctly.

Comment: @RubioRic The application semms to be deployed correctly, there is no error in the Tomcat log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found the problem.

Actually, I added the external Spring jar files to the project classpath and I forget to add them to myProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: i would suggest using maven for maintaining dependencies